# curves with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, circuitikz

I have 5 curves of functions that I want to put in the same TikZ graphic.
The functions are:

```
$$f(x)= 1.5e6(s^(-1/0.06)-1)^(1-0.06)$$
$$g(x)= 10^7(s^(-1/0.412)-1)^(1-0.412)$$
$$h(x)= (1-s^2)*(1-s^(5/3))$$
$$w(x)= (1+(s^(-16.67) - 1)^(1.880) /4)^(-0.5)$$
$$z(x)= (1+(s^(-2.429) -1)^(1.1760))^(-1)$$
```

I tried

```
   \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\foreach \x in {}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\clip(0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=1.0E-4:1.0] plot(\x,{1500000*((\x)^((-1)/0.06)-1)^(1-0.06)});
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=1.0E-4:1.0] plot(\x,{10000000*((\x)^((-1)/0.41)-1)^(1-0.41)});
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=1.0E-4:1.0] plot(\x,{(1-(\x))^2*(1-(\x)^(5/3))});
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=1.0E-4:1.0] plot(\x,{(1+((\x)^(-16.67)-1)^1.88/4)^(-0.5)});
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=1.0E-4:1.0] plot(\x,{(1+((\x)^(-2.43)-1)^1.18)⁻^1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the file not compile in pdf. Olso, i want to make x only beween 0 and 1, and finally, how i can 
put captions on the graph with the color and beside the name of the function for each curve.
Thank's for the help.

Comment: Why do you have doman as `1.0E-4:1.0`? What is `⁻^1` supposed to be?

Comment: Right now it is really not clear which functions you are trying to plot. Typesetting `$z(x)= (1+(s^(-2.429) -1)^(1.1760))^(-1)$`, for example, gives a nonsense result. So although I can reproduce the errors (or, at least, although I can certainly produce errors), I have no idea what would count as correcting those errors.

Comment: For example, should the last one be `$z(x)= (1+(s^{-2.429}-1)^{1.1760})^{-1}$`?

Comment: Look up the syntax for \pgfmathparse (which is what is being used here) starting on page 928 of the pgf manual (v3.0.1a).

Comment: Why you're adding `circuitikz` tag?